# Pandas Replace part of string with value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe (see example, because sensitive data) with a full term (string), a text snippet (one big string) containing the full term and an abbreviation (string). I have been struggling with how to replace the full term *in the text snippet* with the corresponding abbrevation. Can anyone help? Example:

```
    term                      text_snippet                                 abbr
0   aanvullend onderzoek      aanvullend onderzoek is vereist om...        ao/
```

So I want to end up with:

```
    term                      text_snippet                                 abbr
0   aanvullend onderzoek      ao/ is vereist om...                         ao/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` and replace terms with abbrs:

```
df['text_snippet'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x['text_snippet'].replace(x['term'], x['abbr']), axis=1)

df
```

Output:

```
                   term          text_snippet abbr
0  aanvullend onderzoek  ao/ is vereist om...  ao/
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. I made up a simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'term':['United States of America','Germany','Japan'],
              'text_snippet':['United States of America is in America',
                           'Germany is in Europe',
                           'Japan is in Asia'],
              'abbr':['USA','DE','JP']})
df
```

Dataframe before solution:

```
              term              text_snippet                            abbr
0   United States of America    United States of America is in America  USA
1   Germany                     Germany is in Europe                    DE
2   Japan                       Japan is in Asia                        JP
```

Use apply function on every row:

```
df['text_snippet'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['text_snippet'].replace(row['term'],row['abbr']), axis= 1 )
```

Output:

```
                term            text_snippet        abbr
0   United States of America    USA is in America   USA
1   Germany                     DE is in Europe     DE
2   Japan                       JP is in Asia       JP
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! @perl was first but I really appreciate you for helping me out here as well!